# .Net Winform dataRowView error when getting DataBoundItem

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

Sometimes, there are no entries in my datagridview on my WinForm.

But I always validate the rows as follows:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rwX in MyDataGridView.Rows) {
    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView) rwX.DataBoundItem;
     //validation here
}
```

The code believes there are rows so it will enter the foreach statement, but it crashes when it tries to get the DataBoundItem from the first row when the datagrid is showing no items.

I've tried bypassing the method that runs the validation code above with the following if/thens, but all pass and thus run the validation.

```
if (this.bindingSource.Item(0) != null) {
    // run validate method
}

if (this.bindingSource.Count > 0) {
    // run validate method
}

if (this.myDataGridView.Rows(0) != null) {
    // run validate method
}

if (this.myDataGridView.Rows.Count > 0) {
    // run validate method
}
```

I'm not certain why the validation believes there are rows then crashes when it tries to get the DataBountItem from the first row, but I'm hoping to find a way to trap this without a Try Catch

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you have `this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;`? If it's set to `true`, then you could run into the situation where you have no items to show - save the `NewRow`, which would have no `DataBoundItem`. Though - this wouldn't explain why your first two if-statements would still pass.

Comment: Obviously, the crash is a result of trying to use a null value. I am confident that the line…`DataRowView drv = (DataRowView) rwX.DataBoundItem;` will simply return a null value if the data bound item does not exist BUT IT WONT CRASH. It simply returns a null value and throws no exception. If you attempt to USE `drv`… then it will obviously crash. It would appear that a simple check for this possible null value is necessary (as usual) before you attempt to validate the data.

Comment: In addition, I question your statement… _”The code believes there are rows so it will enter the foreach statement”_... If you enter the `foreach` loop… there IS at least ONE (1) row. I am not sure how the code would “believe” otherwise. If you enter the loop, there is a row.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out.  John, the problem was in fact that the crash happened due to filtering the list.  If the currently selected row was, say, row 100, but the filtered list had less than 100 rows, the MyDataGridView.Rows would not have caught up (it thinks I had 100 rows, because that's the row I had selected before applying the filter).  The rwX.DataBoundItem already was updated with the filtered list.  The discrepancy caused the bomb.  The code above was being called by an event, so there is obviously a sequencing problem.  I now will exit the 'for' if the bound row count is exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

If your DataGridView has `AllowUserToAddRows`, then a "new row" is added to the end of the DGV, but it doesn't contain any data yet.

To filter it out, just add a condition on your foreach as follows:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rwX in dataObjectListDataGridView.Rows)
{
    if(!rwX.IsNewRow)
    {
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)rwX.DataBoundItem;
    //validation here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Close, but see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. The problem was due to rwX.DataBoundItem being a null row, obviously, but the reason for the null row was a little more obscure.

It turned out to be due to filtering the list, and then the filtering triggering an event that called the validation code that I show in my question above.

When the event is triggered, MyDataGridView.Rows appears to think that the number of rows equals the row that I had selected in the datagrid--but only if the selected row number is greater than the number of rows in the filtered list.

For example, if I had row 100 selected, but the filtered list only had 99 rows, the foreach would loop through 100 rows and rwX.DataBoundItem would bomb once it looped into the 100th row.  It would bomb because the bound rows had been updated to match the filtered list, which contained only 99 rows, thus rwX.DataBoundItem would return a null value at row 100.

If, one the other hand I had row 1 selected prior to filtering, and the filtered list has 99 rows, then the 'foreach' statement will run correctly through the 99 rows.

It seems to be buggy behavior of Microsoft's datagrid.

Note that after the validation code, which was called by the event, was complete, the discrepancy was automatically cleaned up, so that the MyDataGridView.Rows matched the data Bound Items.

I now tally the rows during the loop and have it exit the 'for' if the bound row count is exceeded, and it works.